# Docker Maven Plugin version 1.4.13 build time takes too long

Tags: docker-maven-plugin

After updating `dockerfile-maven-plugin` version `1.4.10` to `1.4.13` the build times take almost 4 times slower than before.
My maven configuration is the same for both cases.

The git repo : [sample pom file](https://github.com/ibrahimkarayel/message-post/blob/master/pom.xml)
After the clone run the project via `mvn clean install -Pdcoker`

```
build with version: 1.4.13 
[INFO] Total time:  01:39 min
[INFO] Finished at 2019-10-19T11:23:56+02:00


build with version:: 1.4.10
[INFO] Total time:  35.645 s
[INFO] Finished at 2019-10-19T11:18:42+02:00
```

[opened issue link](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven/issues/329)

Comment: same problem here, any solution ?

Comment: unfortunately not yet. You can check the opened issue link below